# Will there be any pin interference in this Project?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on a project with Arduino Uno Clone. After having a look on my arrangement, please tell me whether I will have to face any difficulty or consider any thing.

I have a relay on pin 2 (drive An Induction cooktop from AC Mains),

6 mini 9g servo from pin 3-8 (want to drive non-pwm pins with any Software library),

a 8 ohm speaker on pin 9,

a microSd card module from pin 10-13 (play .wav files through speaker),

5 pushbuttons from pin A0-A4,

a toy dc motor on A5 (Drive through a transistor). So my questions are:

1. Will I have to face any pin arrangement problem in my project? If yes, please give me a solution
2. I have six servos and a dc motor in which only one will be moving at a time, is there really a need of external power source for motors
3. I have to drive this arrangement through AC Mains, but i dont want to buy An adapter. I have a mobile charger which have written "INPUT 100-250V AC, OUTPUT 4-12V, 800mA" , can I drive my arduino with this?
4. Can I boost the volume of my speaker by using a transistor or capacitor (I have no idea about amplifier IC) ?
5. I have to include these librairies, SD library, tmrpcm, SPI, servo, and any one extra to drive servos on non-pwm pins. What would be the total size because my arduino has only 30kb approx?  Thanks To Give Me Time. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. possibly you will face problems with current drain and timing. There is no ready made solution. You have to get a bit farther by yourself and come back with detailed descriptions of your problems.
2. check on other threads (google) the issues with driving directly a coil. There are plenty of explanations why you need to be careful about it.
3. you should at least try to do the math yourself, then ask for verification. Try to calculate the power requirements of each component (average, maximum, peak) and add them up for every scenario. The you can report your finding and ask for confirmation/advice.
4. Sure you can, there are plenty of solutions available, but you have to define your requirements and constraints. Then it's easy to pick one solution (or at least google for it).
5. Just try to include them in the project and compile them. It's fast and you will get the answer immediately. There are ways to optimize things, but first you should assess if it's needed.

All in all, to get more help, you should show more in detail what you have already done, what are your concerns and why.

Comment: Thanks for Your Time. Basically, after seeing your answer I think that there is a very less chance of any type of pin interference. Sorry, because I am just a student without any special technical background. I am googling these topics. If i get any problem, i will Clear it with you